# I want to start a activity if the "edit text" password in entered twice.If the password is entered twice activity should open

Tags: java, android

I want to start an activity if the "edit text" password is entered twice. If the password is entered twice activity should open. This is the method I have,
I'm a basic learner please help me.

```
      public void screen_2(View view) {
          EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


          if (password.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
              password.setError("Password field should not be empty");
          } else {
              String button_text;
              button_text = ((Button) view).getText().toString();

              Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VisaHolderEnquiry.class);
              startActivity(intent1);
          }
      }
```

Comment: Can i know what you need? Do u want to check the password with your string and if its equal you need to go to next activity?

Comment: Hello Nivedh,,,The password is stored in first attempt and in the second attempt ,it should start an activity,

Comment: You should save the password in a sharedpref. so if you access the activity for second time if that value is not empty you should make your app directly go to your activity. Storing password locally is not good but from your question i understood this is what you need right?

Comment: Thank you Nivedh,but how can I achieve that ,can you please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Add text change listener to your text view to monitor text changes and start activity as soon as requirements are met. Read here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

Answer (score 0):

create a counter variable. Increment for every input. Once the value equals to 2, start the required activity.